# How can I update mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a problem that my code did't give me output, it's connect Python to MySql without change the value I want to change, I have 2 scripts file one of them config have my host, password and user and another init

```
import mysql.connector
from config import USER, PASSWORD, HOST


class DbConnectionError(Exception):
    pass
# make a conniction to DB


def _connect_to_db(db_name):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=HOST,
        user=USER,
        password=PASSWORD,
        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
        database=db_name
    )

    return cnx


def change_maximum_mark():
    try:
        db_name = 'tests'
        db_connection = _connect_to_db(db_name)
        cur = db_connection.cursor()
        print(f'connected to database {db_name}')

        query = """
                UPDATE exams
                SET Max_mark = 100
                WHERE Exam_Name = 'Math' 
                """
        cur.execute(query)
        result = cur.fetchall()

        for i in result:
            print(i)

        cur.close()

    except Exception:
        raise DbConnectionError("Failed to read data from DB")

    finally:
        if db_connection:
            db_connection.close()
            print('DB conniction is closed')
```

I run these code to change value in mysql table, I success to connect Python and my sql but unfortunately the value not changed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXn0j.png)

Comment: You haven't committed the transaction: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to commit the query.

Add this piece of code:

```
cur.execute(...query...)
db_connection.commit()
```

Then, I have a question for you: a sql update query does not return any table, so, what are you printing?

I think you should execute a `SELECT` query after the update.

Comment: it works only I forget to off safe update mode, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

the code is right no problem with a code
the problem is using safe update mode , that you must off it with this code.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```